# Reading a file line by line from variable

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I'm working on a script and it isn't clear how `read -r line` knows which variable to get the data from.. I want to read line by line from the FILE variable.

Here is the script I'm working on:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "/"
FILE="$(< /home/FileSystemCorruptionTest/*.chk)" 

while read -r line
do
    echo "$line" > /home/FileSystemCorruptionTest/`date +%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S`_1.log
done

echo "" > /home/FileSystemCorruptionTest/Done
```

Comment: is this a toy example? why do you read the file into a variable?

Comment: I'm reading the contents of a file into a variable because I'll have many while loops proceeding one another

Comment: That doesn't really explain why you don't simply `cat` the file to the log file.  What do you actually want to accomplish? Using a shell loop to process a file line by line is often something you want to avoid.

Comment: This is covered by [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it looks like you want to combine multiple files, I guess that I would regard this as a legitimate usage of `cat`:

```
cat /home/FileSystemCorruptionTest/*.chk | while read -r line
do
    echo "$line"
done > /home/FileSystemCorruptionTest/`date +%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S`_1.log
```

Note that I moved the redirect out of the loop, to prevent overwriting the file once per line.

Also note that your example could easily be written as:

```
cat /home/FileSystemCorruptionTest/*.chk > /home/FileSystemCorruptionTest/`date +%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S`_1.log
```

If you only actually have one file (and want to store it inside a variable), then you can use `<<<` after the loop:

```
while read -r line
do
    echo "$line"
done <<<"$FILE" > /home/FileSystemCorruptionTest/`date +%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S`_1.log
```

`<<< "$FILE"` has the same effect as using `echo "$FILE" |` before the loop but it doesn't create any subshells.

Answer (score 1):

What you are requesting:

```
echo "${FILE}" | while read -r line …
```

But I think Tom's solution is better.